# Cannot Create the Desired Throughput on the IIS Server

Tags: asp.net, performance, iis, performance-testing, perfmon

In short, I am trying to do a load test. But I cannot create the desired throughput on the IIS  server (Windows Server 2016 Datacenter) even though there seems to be no bottleneck in terms of cpu, memory, disk or network.

Here is my configuration:

- **IIS Server:** 16 vCPU, 32GB memory
- **SQL Server:** 4 vCPU, 8GB memory
- **Test Server (sending the requests):** 8 vCPU, 16GB memory

In order to remove concurrency limits on the IIS server, I did the following changes:

```
<serverRuntime appConcurrentRequestLimit="1000000" />

<applicationPool 
        maxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU="1000000"
        maxConcurrentThreadsPerCPU="0" 
        requestQueueLimit="1000000" />

Default Application Pool Queue Length: 65000

<processModel minWorkerThreads="5000">
```

I have created a WPF application that creates the desired number of concurrent requests towards the IIS server using HttpClient and deployed it on the test server. (I changed the service point default connection limit to 1000000 as well.) And I tested with 5000 requests which all returned 200 OK.

Normally, one request returns in 20ms. And here are the results of the test I obtained in the WPF application:

- Total time starting from sending the first request through getting the last response:  **9380ms**
- Average response time : **3919ms**
- Max. response time: **7243ms**
- Min. response time: **77ms**

When I look at the performance counters on the test server, I see that 5000 requests completed in about 3 seconds. Here is the graph I obtained from perfmon:

[image]

But when I look at the performance counters on the IIS server, I see that requests are continually received and executed during the course of 9 seconds. So, the average throughput observed is about 400 requests per second. I also tried the test with 10000 requests but the average throughput is always around 400 req/sec.

[image]

Why doesn't ASP.NET complete receiving all the requests at the end of the first 3 seconds? How can I increase throughput to any desired value so that I can conduct a proper load test?

Comment: 1) Try setting `maxWorkerThreads` to `10000`; if `minWorkerThreads` is larger than `maxWorkerThreads`, it can be ignored. 2) Ensure there's no session state being used.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it but request receiving behavior did not change. I am also monitoring .NET CLR\Locks And Threads. It looks like the number of physical and logical threads are around 30 before sending the requests and rise to around 60 in 2 seconds.

Comment: @StephenCleary And I am not using session state. I am using a Web Api solution initiated with the option "No Authentication". And web.config does not contain anything related to "session". Is there anything else I need to do about it?

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of experimenting, I found out that any value **over 2000** for `minWorkerThreads` seem to be ignored. I checked it using the `ThreadPool.GetMinThreads` method. And I also added the `maxWorkerThreads` value of 2100 as @StephenCleary suggested. With these values, the problem disappeared. But the strange thing is that, I have not seen such a limitation on the `minWorkerThreads` value in any of the MS documentations.